# Proof of the relation between $SO(3)$ generators and their Lie braket

Tags: permutations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensors, kronecker-delta

I'm reading a book called "Physics from symmetry" by Schwichtenberg. The author talks about generators $\{J_i\}$ of the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ and he derives the conditions that they have to fulfill:

$$ J^T + J = 0 $$
$$ \mathrm{tr} J = 0 $$

He finds the following basis:

$$ J_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ J_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ J_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

It is possible to write, as the author say, that:

$$ (J_i)_{jk} = -\varepsilon_{ijk} $$

Then the author claims that by computing the Lie braket, using the found generators, it is possible to write that:

$$ [J_i, J_j] = J_i J_j - J_j J_i = \varepsilon_{ijk} J_k $$

This is the statement I want to prove and so far I came up with this line of reasoning: $(J_i)_{jk} = J_{ijk}$
is a tensor since the Levi-Civita symbol, which $J_i$ can be written in terms of, is itself a tensor. Therefore it is possible to write:

$$ [J_i, J_j]_m^n = (J_i)_{mk} (J_j)^{kn} - (J_j)_{mk} (J_i)^{kn} = J_{imk} J_j^{\ \ kn} - J_{jmk} J_i^{\ \ kn} $$

lowering the indices of the second generator of the couple:

$$ J_{imk} J_j^{\ \ kn} - J_{jmk} J_i^{\ \ kn} = g^{ks} g^{np} J_{imk} J_{jsp} - g^{ks} g^{np} J_{jmk} J_{isp} $$

Then using the fact that $J_{ijk} = -\varepsilon_{ijk}:$

$$ g^{ks} g^{np} \varepsilon_{imk} \varepsilon_{jsp} - g^{ks} g^{np} \varepsilon_{jmk} \varepsilon_{isp} = \varepsilon_{imk} \varepsilon_j^{\ \ kn} - \varepsilon_{jmk} \varepsilon_i^{\ \ kn} = $$
$$ = g_{jl}\varepsilon_{imk} \varepsilon^{lkn} - g_{il}\varepsilon_{jmk} \varepsilon^{lkn} $$
$$ = - g_{jl}\varepsilon_{imk} \varepsilon^{lnk} + g_{il}\varepsilon_{jmk} \varepsilon^{lnk} $$

from which, knowing that $\varepsilon_{mno} \varepsilon^{pqr} = \delta_{mno}^{pqr}$ and that $\delta_{mnk}^{pqk} = 2\delta_{mn}^{pq}$:

$$ - g_{jl}\varepsilon_{imk} \varepsilon^{lnk} + g_{il}\varepsilon_{jmk} \varepsilon^{lnk} =  $$

$$ = - g_{jl} \delta_{imk}^{lnk} + g_{il} \delta_{jmk}^{lnk} = $$
$$ = - 2 g_{jl} \delta_{im}^{ln} + 2 g_{il} \delta_{jm}^{ln} = $$

I'm stuck at this point. I'm not entirely sure that I can treat $J_{ijk}$ as a tensor: the justification I adduced seems pretty weak, as it realies on a way of writing $J_{ijk}$ in terms of $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ and not on the defining property of tensors.
Is the reasoning I'm following correct? And in that case, how do I continue?

P.S.: thanks in advance for any eventual answer and excuse my poor english, as I'm still practising it!

Comment: The Lie bracket here is just the commutator of matrices so the result is just the calculation of $[J_i, J_j] = J_i J_j - J_j J_i$. There is no need for anything tensor-related here. For example $[J_1,J_2] = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0\\  \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0\\  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\  \end{pmatrix} = J_3$

Comment: yes, this is the same example that the author brings, but what I wanted to prove was the general formula, not for a particular case. In the general scenario I can't check for every possible combination of $[J_i, J_j]$, that's the reason why I tried to prove the general formula using variable indices, thus treating $J_{ijk}$ as a tensor

Comment: There's only 3 combinations here (up to swapping the order but that only changes the sign) so you definitely can check them all. If you really wanted to have a general formula then just write out what the $(k,l)$th component of $[J_i, J_j]$ is as a formula and you should be able to deduce it.